# Shopify / Liquid - Change filter search from select dropdown to buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery, select, shopify, liquid

I have got the following code for filtering by product size on my Shopify page. I would like to change it from a select dropdown to individual buttons to filter by size. This will require the script to be changed to accommodate buttons rather than a select, as well as the liquid/html.

**Liquid/HTML**

```
{% assign sizes = '' %}
  {% for product in products limit: limit %}
    {% for variant in product.variants %}
      {% if variant.available %}
        {% assign sizes = sizes | append: variant.options[1] | append: '_' %}
      {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
  {% endfor %}

  {% assign sizesArr = sizes | split: '_' | uniq %}
  <ul class="sortme">
    <li class="clearfix filter">
      <h4>Filter by Size in Stock</h4>
      <select class="styled-select coll-filter">
        <option value="">All</option>
        {% for size in sizesArr %}
          <option value="{{ size }}"{% if current_tags contains size %} selected{% endif %}>{{ size }}</option>
        {% endfor %}
      </select>
    </li>
  </ul>
```

Javascript / jQuery

```
  <script>
    Shopify.queryParams = {};
    if (location.search.length) {
      for (var aKeyValue, i = 0, aCouples = location.search.substr(1).split('&'); i < aCouples.length; i++) {
        aKeyValue = aCouples[i].split('=');
        if (aKeyValue.length > 1) {
          Shopify.queryParams[decodeURIComponent(aKeyValue[0])] = decodeURIComponent(aKeyValue[1]);
        }
      }
    }
    jQuery('.coll-picker').change(function() {
      if (jQuery(this).val()) {
        location.href = '/collections/' + jQuery(this).val();
      }
      else {
        location.href = '/collections/all';
      }
    });
    var collFilters = jQuery('.coll-filter');
    collFilters.change(function() {
      delete Shopify.queryParams.page;
      var newTags = [];
      collFilters.each(function() {
        if (jQuery(this).val()) {
          newTags.push(jQuery(this).val());
        }
      });
      {% if collection.handle %}
      var newURL = '/collections/{{ collection.handle }}';
      if (newTags.length) {
        newURL += '/' + newTags.join('+');
      }
      var search = jQuery.param(Shopify.queryParams);
      if (search.length) {
        newURL += '?' + search;
      }
      location.href = newURL;
      {% else %}
      if (newTags.length) {
        Shopify.queryParams.constraint = newTags.join('+');
      }
      else {
        delete Shopify.queryParams.constraint;
      }
      location.search = jQuery.param(Shopify.queryParams);
      {% endif %}
    });

    $(document).on('shopify:section:load', function(event) {
  Shopify.queryParams = {};
    if (location.search.length) {
      for (var aKeyValue, i = 0, aCouples = location.search.substr(1).split('&'); i < aCouples.length; i++) {
        aKeyValue = aCouples[i].split('=');
        if (aKeyValue.length > 1) {
          Shopify.queryParams[decodeURIComponent(aKeyValue[0])] = decodeURIComponent(aKeyValue[1]);
        }
      }
    }
    jQuery('.coll-picker').change(function() {
      if (jQuery(this).val()) {
        location.href = '/collections/' + jQuery(this).val();
      }
      else {
        location.href = '/collections/all';
      }
    });
    var collFilters = jQuery('.coll-filter');
    collFilters.change(function() {
      delete Shopify.queryParams.page;
      var newTags = [];
      collFilters.each(function() {
        if (jQuery(this).val()) {
          newTags.push(jQuery(this).val());
        }
      });
      {% if collection.handle %}
      var newURL = '/collections/{{ collection.handle }}';
      if (newTags.length) {
        newURL += '/' + newTags.join('+');
      }
      var search = jQuery.param(Shopify.queryParams);
      if (search.length) {
        newURL += '?' + search;
      }
      location.href = newURL;
      {% else %}
      if (newTags.length) {
        Shopify.queryParams.constraint = newTags.join('+');
      }
      else {
        delete Shopify.queryParams.constraint;
      }
      location.search = jQuery.param(Shopify.queryParams);
      {% endif %}
    });
    });
  </script>
```

Comment: Is there a specific part of the task you are struggling with? Like how to get started?

Comment: I changed the above code to use buttons with a slight change to the JS but it results in all tags being searched for at once. So I have gone back to the above code to see if anyone has a fully working solution.